# ExtJS: Converting model columns to rows in a grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm very new to ExtJS and wanted to achieve the following:

I have a model with data something like this:

```
{
   "Account_Enabled": true, 
   "Requirements_gathered": true, 
   "work_done": false, 
   "deadlines": {
     "Account_Enabled": true, 
     "Requirements_gathered": false
    }
}
```

There are no multiple rows. Only a single row returned from the database.

I want to display the data in a grid with three columns
Column1: The name of the column
Column2: A checkbox that shows whether the value is true or false
Column3: A checkbox that shows whether the column name present in "deadlines" or not

Ex:

Account_Enabled       True  True

Requirements_Gathered True  False

work_done             False Undefined(Checkbox need to be disabled)

Basically, i need to convert that single row into three columns.
Also, i need to the update the store when the user checks/uncheks the checkboxes

May i know if there is any way to achieve this via ExtJS grids? or is there any better idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to bind your json response in the format you mention to the grid store.

What you need to do is to manipulate the response the match grid columns required.

Check this working example [ExtJs Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2plo)

```
//Your Original Response
let response = '{"Account_Enabled": true, "Requirements_gathered": true, "work_done": false, "deadlines": {"Account_Enabled": true, "Requirements_gathered": false}}';
// Convert your response to object
let jsonDecode = Ext.decode(response);

//This function to convert your response to match grid store
let dataConvert = function(jsonObj){
    //Returned array object
    let data = [];
    // To get Object of deadlines and know if the property exist or not
    let availableData = jsonObj.deadlines
    //Loop throw object property
    for(var objProperty in jsonObj){
        //Ignore deadlines property
        if(objProperty=="deadlines"){
            continue;
        }
        //Adding the object to the array "objPropery" will return the property name
        //"jsonObj[objProperty]" will return the value of property if it is true or flase
        //"availableData[objProperty]" will return the value if exist in availableData
        data.push({colName:objProperty,isReqGathered:jsonObj[objProperty],isWorkDone:availableData[objProperty]})
    }
    return data
}


let gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'gridStoreId',
    fields: ['colName', 'isReqGathered', 'isWorkDone'],
    data: dataConvert(jsonDecode)
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Test Store Filter',
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: gridStore,
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'colName',
        text: 'colName'
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'isReqGathered',
        text: 'isReqGathered'
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'isWorkDone',
        text: 'isWorkDone'
    }]
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer :) . it is really useful. Displaying the data returned from the store works. But how do i update the database if someone edits any cell? Any suggestions?

Comment: well for the back end you should have bean with 3 property colName,isReqGathered,isWorkDone so you can sen these values from front end to backend and one you have these data in the backend you can write your solution there. So you need data manipulation from the server side

Comment: Hi @moataz Sanad : Backend was reluctant to change the schema/logic. So i workaround it by the following:
in checkchange event, I am formatting the model and calling notify on viewmodel which is in turn sending the data back to the server

<!-- language: lang-js -->

var property = 'data.deadlines.Accounts_enabled'
page.getViewModel().set(property, checked)